# Having trouble with bootstrap Accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a very simple webapp that just lists a few accordian style collapsable entries to display and hide small unordered lists. I've been following a few tutorials as I'm not very experienced with bootstrap, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The collapse feature works just fine, but expanding one does not collapse the other ones. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

## Accordion

```
    <div id="accordian" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#one" data-parent="#accordian" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="one">
                    <h4 class="mb-0">
                        One
                    </h4>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="one" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="card-block">
                  <ul>
                      <li>A</li>
                      <li>B</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#two" data-parent="#accordian" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="two">
                    <h4 class="mb-0">
                        Two
                    </h4>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="two" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="card-block">
                  <ul>
                      <li>C</li>
                      <li>D</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div data-role="footer">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the collapsable items to act as an accordion (collapsing all other collapsable elements when one is opened) you need to add class 'panel-group' to the enclosing div element which contains the collapsable elements. Then just add class 'panel' to all panels within the panel group div.

```html
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordian" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel card">
            <div class="card-header " role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#one" data-parent="#accordian" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="one">
                    <h4 class="mb-0">
                        One
                    </h4>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="one" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="card-block">
                  <ul>
                      <li>A</li>
                      <li>B</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#two" data-parent="#accordian" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="two">
                    <h4 class="mb-0">
                        Two
                    </h4>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="two" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="card-block">
                  <ul>
                      <li>C</li>
                      <li>D</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```